# I can't create this procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to create new stored procedure with this code, this error always appear to me:

```sql
    CREATE PROCEDURE `retriveData`() NOT DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL
    SECURITY DEFINER  BEGIN

    SET @sql = NULL
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 4

I used this code to create stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE `retriveData`() NOT DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
BEGIN

    SET @sql = NULL;
    SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
          'MAX(IF(pa.item = ''',
          item,
          ''', pa.comValue, 0)) AS ',
          item
        )
      ) INTO @sql
    FROM salaryStructureView;

    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT p.id
                        , p.fullname
                        , p.salary, ', @sql, ' 
                       FROM employee p
                       LEFT JOIN salaryStructureView AS pa 
                        ON p.id = pa.id
                       GROUP BY p.id');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Comment: My first guess is that you need a `delimiter` statement.

Comment: Do you need to declare variables in MariaDB? (I don't actually know, but in most SQL flavors you do)

Comment: @JacobH, you don't in MySQL, so I assume not in Maria either.

Comment: You have to declare Variables in order to use them in code, but session variables like @sql don't need to be declared.

Comment: Can I create view including variables like previous example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a delimiter:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `retriveData`() NOT DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
BEGIN

SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(pa.item = ''',
      item,
      ''', pa.comValue, 0)) AS ',
      item
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM salaryStructureView;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT p.id
                    , p.fullname
                    , p.salary, ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM employee p
                   LEFT JOIN salaryStructureView AS pa 
                    ON p.id = pa.id
                   GROUP BY p.id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
$$
```

Comment: this error appeared #1558 - Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 21, found 20. Created with MariaDB 100108, now running 100408. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error

Comment: I found the answer in this issue "mysql upgrade (5.0.45 to 5.1.42) error"